# Constructing a real analogue of a complex Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, hilbert-spaces

I've been told that, for every complex Hilbert space $(\mathcal{H},\langle \cdot\,|\,\cdot\rangle)$ we can construct a real Hilbert space which is "the same", which perhaps means isomorphic? and I'm curious if y'all know of a good reference on the topic.

I've read that constructing the new inner product to be $\textrm{Re}(\langle\cdot\,|\,\cdot\rangle)$ is a common construction. However, I have lots of questions, e.g. do these constructions yield the exact same distances? What about projections onto closed convex sets, and all the other "nice" stuff that comes along with working in a Hilbert space?

Comment: If $\mathcal{H}$ is a complex Hilbert space and $\mathcal{K}$ is a real Hilbert space, what do you mean by an embedding of $\mathcal{H}$ into $\mathcal{K}$?

Comment: @ChrisEagle Thanks for the question, I should clarify that the claim is **given** a complex Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, we can **construct** another real Hilbert space which is isomorphic (in some sense) to $\mathcal{H}$. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\mathcal H$ is a complex Hilbert space. There is a standard way to view it is a real vector space, where if $\mathcal B$ is a Hamel basis for $\mathcal H$, then $\mathcal B \cup i \mathcal B$ is a Hamel basis for $\mathcal H$ as a real vector space.

If $\langle x, y\rangle$ is the inner product over $\mathcal H$, define $(\cdot, \cdot) : \mathcal H \times \mathcal H \to \mathbb R$ by $(x,y) = Re \langle x, y\rangle$. This is the construction you reference in the post. But so long as $\mathcal H \ne \{0\}$, this is not an inner product. Take $v \ne 0$, then $(iv, v) = Re \langle iv,v \rangle = Re (i \|v\|^2) =0$.

In general, there can't really be an "isomorphism" of a complex inner product space into a real inner product space. For inner product spaces, an isomorphism needs to preserve inner products. You can't preserve inner product going from a complex space to a real space, unless all the inner products are real, which happens iff your space is trivial.

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation!